# Programmatically loaded taxonomy form ajax errors

Tags: 7, forms, taxonomy-terms, ajax

I load a taxonomy term in the edit form via the following code:

```
module_load_include ( 'inc', 'taxonomy', 'taxonomy.admin' );
$vocabulary = taxonomy_term_load ( $tid );
$form = drupal_get_form ( 'taxonomy_form_term', $vocabulary );
```

The vocabulary has a custom text field with unlimited values, so this appears on the form, but when I click the "add another item" button, I get:

> Call to undefined function, taxonomy_form_term_validate() in [truncated path].../form.inc" on line 1513.

[image]

I appreciate any guidance I can get in solving this.

Comment: Where do make the ajax? It can be the case that you are not bootstrapping the necessary files in the ajax.

Comment: Potney, this is just the "add another item" button that appears under a field that's set to have unlimited values.

Answer (score 0):

This function worked for me:
Please try to use form_load_include() and drupal_build_form() instead of drupal_get_form() to generate form

```
  $form_id = 'taxonomy_form_term';
  $vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_load($tid);

  $form_state = array();
  $form_state['build_info']['args'] = array($vocabulary);

  // use form_load_include() and drupal_build_form() instead of drupal_get_form()
  form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'taxonomy', 'taxonomy.admin');

  $form = drupal_build_form($form_id, $form_state);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid); $form_state['build_info']['args'] = array($term);`?